# Python and Tkinter, carry list info from one function to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on a project. I set a toplevel, a listbox and textbox on the toplevel. I want to have a function that is called when I click on one of the elements of the list, and then I want to get the index of the selected element, and update the textbox. Any ideas?

This is the code I have, but it doesn't do what I want it to do:

```
def helpInitialize():
    help = Toplevel()
    help.title("Help")
    help.geometry("1000x650")
    help.resizable(0,0)

    helpFiles= []

    listy = Scrollbar(help)
    listy.place(x=143, y=20, height=565)

    listHelp = Listbox(help, height=35, width=20)
    listHelp.place(x=20, y=20)
    listHelp.config(yscrollcommand=listy.set)
    listy.config(command=listHelp.yview)

    texty = Scrollbar(help)
    texty.place(x= 977, y= 20, height = 565)
    textx = Scrollbar(help,orient= HORIZONTAL)
    textx.place(x = 175, y= 583, width = 800)

    helpText = Text(help, bg="white", height=35, width=100)
    helpText.place(x=175, y=20)
    helpText.configure(state="disabled")
    helpText.config(yscrollcommand=texty.set, xscrollcommand=textx.set)
    texty.config(command=helpText.yview)
    textx.config(command=helpText.xview)

    listHelp.bind("<Button-1>", theFunction)

def theFunction(event):
    print(listHelp.get(listHelp.curselection()))
```

Comment: Read up on [scopes-and-namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can use `lambda` to pass the `Listbox` and `Text` widgets to the function:

```
listHelp.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: theFunction(e.widget, helpText))
```

Modify `theFunction()`:

```
def theFunction(listbox, textbox):
    index = listbox.curselection()[0]
    value = listbox.get(index)
    textbox.insert(tk.END, str(value)+'\n')
    textbox.see(tk.END)
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically, I'll put my tkinter objects into a class. It makes it much easier to share objects between functions. Here is an example of how that could be achieved with the sample code you provided.

```
from tkinter import Toplevel, Scrollbar, Listbox, Text, HORIZONTAL, END

class Help:
    def __init__(self):
        self.help = Toplevel()
        self.help.title("Help")
        self.help.geometry("1000x650")
        self.help.resizable(0,0)

        self.helpFiles = ['Test ' + str(i) for i in range(100)]

        self.listy = Scrollbar(self.help)
        self.listy.place(x=143, y=20, height=565)

        self.listHelp = Listbox(self.help, height=35, width=20)
        self.listHelp.place(x=20, y=20)
        self.listHelp.config(yscrollcommand=self.listy.set)
        self.listy.config(command=self.listHelp.yview)

        for item in self.helpFiles:
            self.listHelp.insert(END, item)

        self.texty = Scrollbar(self.help)
        self.texty.place(x= 977, y= 20, height = 565)
        self.textx = Scrollbar(self.help, orient= HORIZONTAL)
        self.textx.place(x = 175, y= 583, width = 800)

        self.helpText = Text(self.help, bg="white", height=35, width=100)
        self.helpText.place(x=175, y=20)
        self.helpText.configure(state="disabled")
        self.helpText.config(yscrollcommand=self.texty.set, xscrollcommand=self.textx.set)
        self.texty.config(command=self.helpText.yview)
        self.textx.config(command=self.helpText.xview)

        self.listHelp.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.theFunction)

    def theFunction(self, event):
        print(self.listHelp.get(self.listHelp.curselection()))
        # your code here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Help()
    test.help.mainloop()
```

Additionally I changed your function binding from `<Button-1>` to `<<ListboxSelect>>`. I believe that one has the functionality you desired.